# PHP class to easily use SQLite3 on PHP?

Tags: php, class, sqlite

Does someone has or know a php class to easily use SQLite3 on PHP?

I has been using this one http://code.jenseng.com/db/ but it's for sqlite2 dbs.

I used it to execute queries and fetch arrays of results, I've found one but its a huge code, I was looking for something simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should be able to do so with the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php) class (Cross DBMS).

Answer (score 11):

[PHP has a native SQLite3 class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php), which is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0

Example from [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.construct.php)

```
$db = new SQLite3('mysqlitedb.db');
$db->exec('CREATE TABLE foo (bar STRING)');
$db->exec("INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('This is a test')");
$result = $db->query('SELECT bar FROM foo');
var_dump($result->fetchArray());
```

Comment: The debian 8 package version of php `PHP 5.6.20-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Apr 27 2016 11:26:05) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies` comes without sqlite and have to be installed via `apt-get install php5-sqlite`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using PDO:

http://www.php.net/PDO

See the examples and comments for `fetchAll()`